Select specific Column forma table based on selected name
Help me to solve this issue:

I have table with name: "TbName";
The table have 3 columns: "Maria", "John", "Manuel";
I want show just one colunm of the table in a subform ("frmName").
The showed colunm must change each time I change the name in a combobox ("combo_name") from the subform.

I have tried to create a query:
SELECT [frmName]![combo_name] FROM tbName;
When in run it. It ask me for [frmName]![combo_name].
Even when i write "Manuel" it create a table with only a column "frmname]![combo_name.

Field name in query object cannot be dynamic. What is the data? Why do you have 3 similar fields instead of just one? You probably should normalize data structure. Then you can apply filter for whatever name records you want to view. Otherwise, use code to change form RecordSource or textbox ControlSource.

^This. You really should rework your table design. Good table design leads to better working frontends, without the need for strange workarounds.

You must rewrite the query for the subform in the AfterUpdate event of the combobox:
Private Sub combo_name_AfterUpdate()

    Dim Sql As String

    Sql = "SELECT " & Me!combo_name.Value & " FROM tbName"
    Me!NameOfYourSubformCONTROL.Form.RecordSource = Sql

End Sub

Note that on your main form, NameOfYourSubformCONTROL is the name of the subform control holding subform frmName.
